# POST variables in PHP Slim rest api

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to get a POST variable,  does Slim have a special way of retrieve parameters ? sending parameter in http body.

For example, if I wanted to use the following:

```
 http://localhost:5057/PB/App/
```

And `BnkId=910155&Acc=0020150010561` are parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$BnkId = $app->request->params('BnkId');
$Acc = $app->request->params('Acc');
```

Read the documentation at [Slim documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/request/variables/)

Comment: thank you for answer ,when  tried to access document then 404 was there